# Can the installation of a github-app to our repos be automated

Tags: git, github, token

I want to automate the installation of a github-app to a repo. Is there a way to do it via token and using git apis. Or can someone suggest a workaround for this use-case.

https://docs.github.com/en/apps/using-github-apps/installing-a-github-app-from-github-marketplace-for-your-organizations instead of this can I automate this for users to install my app?